# What is the probability this random walk ends at a specific end point?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

If the random walk hits points A or B it stops. Consider the symmetric RW on a graph constructed from the two complete graphs $K_{m}$ and $K_{n}$  in such a way that the two complete graphs have exactly 2 common vertices. S is one of the common vertices. Assume that A and B are end points in the graph, and let m = $10^{6}$ and n = 2 * $10^{6}$ (i.e., million and two-million).
I am interested in the probability that the symmetric random walk, starting from S, dies in point A. Give an approximation of the value of this probability.

Consider this figure for a visual reference, where m=4,n=5. 
I am interested in solving the case m = $10^{6}$ and n = 2 * $10^{6}$ and calculating the probability the random walk ends at Point A. Is the answer simply 1/3 as $K_{n}$ is twice as big $K_{m}$?

[image: Figure for reference]

I improved the wording on my previous question.

Comment: In the future, you should edit a question rather than repost it as a second, separate question; having two versions of a question around is confusing.

Comment: Idea: In each complete graph, all the points (except $A$ and the two transition points) are identical. So you can collapse it to a 3 point graph with very high probability to remain in the same place, a small probability to go to a transition point and small probability to go to $A$. Same with the second graph.